# How to delete specific characters from a string in a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to delete the last two characters from values in a column.

The values of the PySpark dataframe look like this:

```
1000.0
1250.0
3000.0
...
```

and they should look like this:

```
1000
1250
3000
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` to get the string until the index `length - 2`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'col', 
    F.expr("substring(col, 1, length(col) - 2)")
)
```

Comment: something is not working, I think it has something to do with "substring(col, 1, length(col) - 2)" being read as a string. I might be wrong. iI the usage of col always the name of the column, or is it an argument?

Comment: it should be the name of the column. what error are you getting?

Comment: my column name is Belgium postalcodes, do you think the space in it is the problem? cause the error points to that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regexp_replace`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("value", F.regexp_replace("value", "(.*).{2}", "$1"))

df1.show()

#+-----+
#|value|
#+-----+
#| 1000|
#| 1250|
#| 3000|
#+-----+
```

Or `regexp_extract`:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("value", F.regexp_extract("value", "(.*).{2}", 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`substring_index`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index) to extract the part before the period:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['1000.0'], ['2000.0']], ['col'])
df.withColumn('new_col', F.substring_index(F.col('col'), '.', 1))
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+
|   col|new_col|
+------+-------+
|1000.0|   1000|
|2000.0|   2000|
+------+-------+
```